# Subversion project re-organisation

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

- Prior to my joining, the SVN project repository has been set up with 4 top-level `Release` folders.
- We only aim to have 1 production system at the end of our work.
- Each of the `Release` folders has its own `branches` / `tags` / `trunk` folders.

The `Release` folders are fine for the dev teams to work in, however for overall config of the system, I need to merge these `Release` folders into a single `Integration` folder set.

I would do the following:

Branching from `Release 1` to a new `Integration` branch folder and then merging the contents of each of the subsequent `Release` folders into that.

Can you recommend a better approach or the one I have in mind will work and is sufficient? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

From your scenario the structure below is sufficient

- Branch
- Tags
- Trunk

The **Trunk** will always contain the code for **upcoming** production release. Your **Tags** will contain the code of your released version of your application. As for the **Branch** you can have future release version and your development team will developed against it. You will need to make sure your **Branch** are in sync with the current release **Trunk** by having a regular merge. Ideally the merge is done weekly or once every 2 weeks.  In terms of merging you will encounter conflicts/wrinkles and it is a matter of ironing it out.

Answer (score 0):

With the description you provided, it seems to be the way to...

Add a new top-level folder `Integration` and create `branches`/`tags`/`trunk`.

Now `Release1` is your initial point and you can keep on merging `Release2`,`Release3` & `Release4`

Every `Integration` testing changes can be done in `branch` and `tag` can be cut to identify the state of your production end system.